# Replace unknown values with NaN in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet which I imported to pandas dataframe.
There are unknown values in the dataframe with value = '\N'
I want to replace this with np.Nan.

I got to know how to replace it for one column. Is there a way I can iterate it through the entire dataframe and replace all the occurences of '\N' with Nan

I tried this and it worked for one column

```py
import numpy as np
df['column_name'].replace(r'\N', np.nan, inplace = True)
```

How do I do it for the entire dataframe.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call the `replace` on the `df` itself. `df.replace(r'\N', np.nan, inplace = True)`

Comment: Use `df = df.replace(r'\N', np.nan)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same but for the all df
`df.replace(r'\N', np.nan, inplace = True)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also call .replace() on the entire dataframe instead of a single column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, r"\N"]])
df.replace(r"\N", np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save time by declaring what `np.nan` should be when you first `import` the file in python:

```
import pandas as pd

na_values = ['\N','NAN','Nan','""',] # add all values that should be converted to np.nan
df=pd.read_excel('test.xls',na_values= na_values, keep_default_na = False)
```

This should automatically treat them as `np.nan`